# How did I get the git commits to show up in autocomplete?

Tags: zsh, git, autocomplete

Git tab completion on my mac:

[image: Git tab completion on my mac]

Git tab completion on my Ubuntu server:

[image: Git tab completion on my ubuntu server]

On my mac and my Ubuntu server I get very different output from tab completion despite having the same version of zsh, same version of git, the same version of oh-my-zsh, and the same .zshrc file.

I wanted to know what is giving me the ability to see commits on my mac using tab completion so that I can set it up on my ubuntu server.

Comment: Are you using the same git command in both cases?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your terminal. Instead, copy/paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in Zsh on your Ubuntu server, you might have Git's `_git` function in your `$fpath` before Zsh's `_git` function. Git's version is just an automatic port of its Bash completion and lacks many of the features that Zsh's version has.

To find out if this is the case, do `ls ${^fpath}/_git(N)` on both machines and compare. When you find the offending file, remove it or make sure that Zsh's file comes first.